# What's the correct type for error in useRouteError() from react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using the useRouteError() hook from react-router-dom in a React project to catch any errors that may occur during routing. However, I'm not sure what the correct type for the error object returned by this hook is.

Right now, I have declared the error as any in my component, which is not ideal. I'd like to declare the correct type for the error object to make my code more robust.

Can someone please tell me what the correct type is for the error object returned by useRouteError() in react-router-dom?

```
import { useRouteError } from 'react-router-dom'

const ErrorPage: React.FC = () => {
  const error: any = useRouteError() // Add appropriate type here
  return (
    <div
      id='error-page'
      className='flex flex-col gap-8 justify-center items-center h-screen'
    >
      <h1 className='text-4xl font-bold'>Oops!</h1>
      <p>Sorry, an unexpected error has occurred.</p>
      <p className='text-slate-400'>
        <i>{error.statusText || error.message}</i>
      </p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ErrorPage
```

Comment: ...what type does that hook _say_ it returns? Have you read e.g. https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/discussions/9628?

Comment: The official type is [unknown](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/lib/hooks.tsx#L822). If you need something more specific then cast to your error type.

Answer (score 29):

`useRouteError` has a correct type of `unknown` since you can throw anything from your loaders or actions. You should use type narrowing to infer the error type as [suggested by one of the maintainers of React Router](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/discussions/9628#discussioncomment-5555901).

Here is an example of how you can use the `isRouteErrorResponse(error)` helper method:
(Note how you don't need to explicitly set error to `unknown`)

```
import React from 'react';
import { useRouteError, isRouteErrorResponse } from 'react-router-dom';

const ErrorPage: React.FC = () => {
  // you don't need to explicitly set error to `unknown`
  const error = useRouteError();
  let errorMessage: string;

  if (isRouteErrorResponse(error)) {
    // error is type `ErrorResponse`
    errorMessage = error.error?.message || error.statusText;
  } else if (error instanceof Error) {
    errorMessage = error.message;
  } else if (typeof error === 'string') {
    errorMessage = error;
  } else {
    console.error(error);
    errorMessage = 'Unknown error';
  }

  return (
    <div id='error-page' className='flex flex-col gap-8 justify-center items-center h-screen'>
      <h1 className='text-4xl font-bold'>Oops!</h1>
      <p>Sorry, an unexpected error has occurred.</p>
      <p className='text-slate-400'>
        <i>{errorMessage}</i>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ErrorPage;
```

Comment: I get the following error for `error.error?.message`: Property 'error' is private and only accessible within class 'ErrorResponseImpl'.ts(2341)

Comment: @Fedorov7890 seems to be an update: `error.data.message` now works for me.

Comment: @Fedorov7890 try copy/paste directly from original suggestion (linked in answer), it has no errors

Answer (score 7):

Thanks, I have solved the error like this.

Added this in compiler option `useUnknownInCatchVariables: true` in `tsconfig`.

```
import { useRouteError } from 'react-router-dom'

const ErrorPage: React.FC = () => {
  const error: unknown = useRouteError()
  return (
    <div
      id='error-page'
      className='flex flex-col gap-8 justify-center items-center h-screen'
    >
      <h1 className='text-4xl font-bold'>Oops!</h1>
      <p>Sorry, an unexpected error has occurred.</p>
      <p className='text-slate-400'>
        <i>
          {(error as Error)?.message ||
            (error as { statusText?: string })?.statusText}
        </i>
      </p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ErrorPage
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this way

```react
import {
    useNavigate,
    isRouteErrorResponse,
    useRouteError,
} from 'react-router-dom';

export const Error = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const error = useRouteError() as Error;

    if (!isRouteErrorResponse(error)) {
        return null;
    }

    

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Something went wrong </h1>
            <p>{error.data}</p>
            <button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>&larr; Go back</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: I didn't understand this line very well ```const error = useRouteError() as Error;``` 
Is ```Error``` considered as a type ?

Otherwise, I think your answer is nice! It works on my side, I had the same issue as Sadik.

Comment: @Laila this line is an assertion. It considers useError as Error it means ts understand that it can use Error with this methods

Answer (score 1):

```
import { useRouteError } from 'react-router-dom';

interface RouteError {
  data: string;
  error: {
    columnNumber: number;
    fileName: string;
    lineNumber: number;
    message: string;
    stack: string;
  };
  internal: boolean;
  status: number;
  statusText: string;
}

export default function ErrorPage() {
  const error = useRouteError() as RouteError;

  return (
    <div id="error-page">
      <h1>Oops!</h1>
      <p>Sorry, an unexpected error has occurred.</p>
      <p>
        <i>{error.statusText || error.error.message}</i>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```